# Same VueX store module registered from components on two pages

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

I have encountered a weird case when using VueX and Vue-Router and I am not too sure how to cleanly solve it.

I have a component (let's call it "ComponentWithStore") that registers a named store module a bit like this : (the actual content of the store don't matter. obviously in this toy example using VueX is overkill, but this is a very simplified version of a much more complexe app where using VueX makes sense)

```
// ComponentWithStore.vue
<script>
import module from './componentStore.js';

export default {
    name: 'ComponentWithStore',
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.registerModule(module.name, module);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        this.$store.unregisterModule(module.name);
    }
}
</script>
```

Then I place this component in a view (or page) which is then associated to a route (let's call this page "Home").

```
// Home.vue
<template>
  <div class="home">
    Home
    <ComponentWithStore/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentWithStore from '@/components/ComponentWithStore.vue';

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: { ComponentWithStore }
};
</script>
```

So far so good, when I visit the Home route, the store module is registered, and when I leave the Home route the store module is cleaned up.

Let's say I then create a new view (page), let's call it "About", and this new About page is basically identical to Home.vue, in that it also uses ComponentWithStore.

```
// About.vue
<template>
  <div class="about">
    About
    <ComponentWithStore/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentWithStore from '@/components/ComponentWithStore.vue';

export default {
  name: "About",
  components: { ComponentWithStore }
};
</script>
```

Now I encounter the following error when navigating from Home to About :

```
vuex.esm.js?2f62:709 [vuex] duplicate namespace myComponentStore/ for the namespaced module myComponentStore
```

What happens is that the store module for "About" is registered *before* the store module for "Home" is unregistered, hence the duplicate namespace error.

So I understand well what the issue is, however I am unsure what would be the cleanest solution to solve this situation. All ideas are welcome

A full sample may be found here : https://github.com/mmgagnon/vue-module-router-clash
To use, simply run it and switch between the Home and About pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, the issue is due to the ordering of the hooks. You just need to use the correct hooks to ensure that the old component unregisters the module first before the new component registers it again.

At a high level, here is the order of hooks in your situation when navigating from Home to About:

1. About beforeCreate
2. About created
3. Home beforeDestroy
4. Home destroyed
5. About mounted

So you can register the module in the `mounted` hook and unregister it in either `beforeDestroy` or `destroyed`.

I haven't tested this though. It might not work if your component requires access to the store after it is created and before it is mounted.

---

A better approach is to create an abstraction to register and unregister modules that allows for overlaps.

Untested, but something like this might work:

```js
function RegistrationPlugin(store) {
  const modules = new Map()

  store.registerModuleSafely = function (name, module) {
    const count = modules.get(name) || 0

    if (count === 0) {
      store.registerModule(name, module)
    }

    modules.set(name, count + 1)
  }

  store.unregisterModuleSafely = function (name) {
    const count = modules.get(name) || 0

    if (count === 1) {
      store.unregisterModule(name)
      modules.delete(name)
    } else if (count > 1) {
      modules.set(name, count - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Specify the plugin when you create your store:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [RegistrationPlugin]
})
```

Now register and unregister your modules like this:

```js
beforeCreate() {
  this.$store.registerModuleSafely(module.name, module)
},

destroyed() {
  this.$store.unregisterModuleSafely(module.name)
}
```

Comment: Using mounted does not work because in the real case, I have "computed"s that use getters from the store, and those computeds get evaluated before mounted and crash. Your plugin idea is however very interesting and I will be investigating that